# Passing height and other style attributes of a component from app builder to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

I am trying to implement functionality where I can change the `background-color`, `height` and other parameters of a lightning web component. However, I am not able to see whether it reflected in the component. For now, I am providing the height of the component through app builder and I am able to log the value on the screen. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Below is my code snippet:

## .js

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ARE_DisplaySameObjectFields extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api componentHeight;

    get style() {
        return this.componentHeight;
    }

    set style(value) {
        this.componentHeight = value;
        this.setAttribute('style', "height: " + this.componentHeight);
    }       
}
```

## .html

```html
<template>
    <div style={componentHeight}></div>
</template>
```

## .js-meta.xml

```xml
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage">
        <property name="componentHeight" type="Integer" default="200" min="200" max="500" label="Component height"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. You are configuring style in js but again passing `componentHeight` to template directly .
2. `style` should have been a getter .
3. You are passing just an integer as height - this will not work unless its added with `px` or `rem` or etc

**Sample SOLUTION**:

HTML:

```
<div style={componentStyle}> Some div text </div>
```

JS:

```
@api height;
@api background;
@api color;

get componentStyle() {
    return `height:${this.height}px;background:${this.background};color:${this.color};`;
}
```

meta:

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage">
        <property name="height" type="Integer" default="200" min="200" max="500" label="Component height" description="Should be in pixels (px)" />
        <property name="background" type="String" default="white" label="Background"/>
        <property name="color" type="String" default="black" label="Text Color"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

**APP BUILDER:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance.